# Access 2013 Requesting Enter Parameter On Insert Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've got a list box that pulls tests from a database depending on the college any particular student is in.  When the student selects a test, I simply want to pull a few values out of the List box for stat tracking purposes.  When I run this query, it requests I enter a parameter value.

Here is my code:

```
'Dim TestName As String
 TestName = Me.List15.Column(1)


DoCmd.RunSQL ("Insert Into TestingStatistics (BadgeNumber, TestName, College, Instructor, SigninTime, Special)" _
& "VALUES (" & txtBadgeNo.Value & ", " & TestName & ", 'Medicine', 'Test', time(), 1);")
```

On `TestName` it's requesting that I enter a parameter value.  I've tried running this with a messagebox and it's pushing the right information.  Even the Enter Parameter value dialog that pops up has the correct information in it as a caption.

What am I missing?

Comment: Access is not MySQL. Please do not use inappropriate tags.

Comment: Sorry, it recommended it I wasn't sure, I'll remove it.

Comment: I see you fixed it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a String, not a Variant, and a space:

```
Dim TestName As String
TestName = Nz(Me.List15.Column(1))

DoCmd.RunSQL ("Insert Into TestingStatistics (BadgeNumber, TestName, College, Instructor, SigninTime, Special) " & _
"VALUES (" & txtBadgeNo.Value & ", '" & TestName & "', 'Medicine', 'Test', Time(), 1);")
```